# Use Solve[] with Bessel, gamma, and hypergeometric functions?

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I need to find values of {a,b,c} such that the 0th, 2nd, and 4th order moments of f[x]=Exp[-a*x^4 - b*x^2 - c] will equal respectively {1,2,10}.

I didn't really expect this to work, and it didn't:

```
Solve[{
  Integrate[Exp[-a*x^4 - b*x^2 - c], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 1,
  Integrate[(x^2)*Exp[-a*x^4 - b*x^2 - c], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 2,
  Integrate[(x^4)*Exp[-a*x^4 - b*x^2 - c], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 10},{a, b, c}]
```

Is there any clever way I can use Mathematica to solve this problem without having to write my own custom iterative solver?  (I will settle for a non-clever way.)

Comment: Does `{a -> 0.0108063, b -> 0.141937, c -> 1.36499}` float your boat? If so, set it up for use of `FindRoot`...

Comment: `Solve[]` is really only intended for algebraics and "simple" transcendentals. Things as complicated as yours require the use of `FindRoot[]` along with some amount of numerical/analytic insight on where the roots might be.

Comment: [In any case…](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11364)

Comment: @J. M.: Seriously nice answer ref'd there, +1 there!

Comment: @ciao, thanks, but Maxim and Daniel really should get the lions' share of the credit; I wouldn't have been able to come up with that if Daniel hadn't answered my other question. :)

Comment: Jerry, a tip: consider using the [Kummer transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E39) on your expressions to ease the numerics.