# Finding "Maxima" and "Minima" on a B-Spline

Tags: equation-solving, splines

I need to find the "Maxima" and "Minima" on a B-Spline or more correct the points where the 2nd components of the derivate equal zero.

For example:

```
g = BSplineFunction[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, -1}, {4, 2}}] ; 
dg=g';
Solve[{dg[t][[2]] == 0, 0 <= t <= 1}, t]
```

The problem is that "Solve" wont work for this kind of application, and "Minimize"  or similar functions stop at the first finding.

Any ideas?
CX

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `MeshFunctions` to do the trick:

```
g = BSplineFunction[{RandomReal[1, 20], RandomReal[1, 20]}\[Transpose]];

dg = g';

ParametricPlot[
    g[t], {t, 0, 1},
    MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, t}, dg[t].{0, 1}],
    Mesh -> {{0}},
    MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Red]
    ]
```

[image: extrema meshed spline]

Here the `MeshFunctions` specifies the value of `dg[t].{0, 1}`, *i.e.* the $y$ component of the tangential vector of $g(t)$ at $t$, is used to generate mesh levels. Then `Mesh -> {{0}}` specifies that we only draw meshes where `dg[t].{0, 1} == 0`, which is exactly the extrema of $g(t)$.

To tell maxima from minima, use the `RegionFunction`:

```
maximapart = ParametricPlot[
                 g[t], {t, 0, 1},
                 PlotStyle -> Lighter[Blue, .6],
                 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, g''[t].{0, 1} < 0],
                 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, t}, dg[t].{0, 1}],
                 Mesh -> {{0}},
                 MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Red]
                 ]

minimapart = ParametricPlot[
                 g[t], {t, 0, 1},
                 PlotStyle -> Lighter[Brown, .6],
                 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, t}, g''[t].{0, 1} > 0],
                 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, t}, dg[t].{0, 1}],
                 Mesh -> {{0}},
                 MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Blue]
                 ]

Show[{maximapart, minimapart}]
```

[image: styled maxima and minima]

Extracting the points is straightforward:

```
maximaptSet = Cases[maximapart, GraphicsComplex[pt_, __] :> pt, ∞][[1]];
maximaIdx = Cases[maximapart, Point[pt_] :> pt, ∞][[1]];
maximaptSet[[maximaIdx]]

minimaptSet = Cases[minimapart, GraphicsComplex[pt_, __] :> pt, ∞][[1]];
minimaIdx = Cases[minimapart, Point[pt_] :> pt, ∞][[1]];
minimaptSet[[minimaIdx]]
```

Comment: Very nice use of 1D MeshFunction

Comment: @chris Thanks. I realized this trick only a couple of days ago! :D

Comment: could it be used to my problem? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9928/1089  just a thought?

Comment: @chris Ah That's an interesting question. I upvoted at that time but didn't come up with any useful thought. Please allow me try tomorrow. Now I'm going to have some sleep :)

Comment: Something like that ought to work? `dat = GaussianRandomField[nn = 32] // Chop;
dat /= Max[dat]; dat *= nn/2;
dat2 = Table[{i, j, dat[[i, j]]}, {i, nn}, {j, nn}];
bs = BSplineFunction[dat2];
dbs = Function[{u, v}, Sqrt[Derivative[1, 0][bs][u, v][[3]]^2 +
      Derivative[0, 1][bs][u, v][[3]]^2] // Evaluate];
ParametricPlot3D[bs[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, dbs[u, v]], 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[Small], Red], Mesh -> {{0}}]`

Comment: @chris I played with your code a while, and I think the direction is hopeful. Only one thing to be noticed: I think `MeshFunctions` detects the mesh when the surface **crosses** the specific mesh value. So it can detect a mesh value $a$ like $f(x<a)<0\land f(x>a)>0$, but may be theoretically impossible to detect one like $f(x\neq a)>0$, which is the case in your code. So I think you'll have to rephrase your `MeshFunctions` in a "cross-value" manner.

Comment: Thank you for your interest; it seems it behaves strangely on the edges though; and misses a few extrema as in this [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FHRo6.png). Still its fast so it might be worth digging.

Comment: @chris Like I said in my last comment, your $f^2+g^2$ style setting will not *cross* 0 but only *"touch"* 0, so it's not a good way to specify `MeshFunctions`. Maybe you can [draw mesh lines of $f=0$ and $g=0$ separately](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nyH1K.png) and find the cross of them.

Comment: you are right. Would you know how to extract those crossing? (from the graphics rather than using e.g. `FindAllCrossings2D`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14058/discussion-between-silvia-and-chris)

Answer (score 8):

A more interesting example with multiple extrema..

```
 g = BSplineFunction[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, -1}, {4, 2}, {5, 0}, {6, 1}}];
 gp = g';
 gpy[t_?NumericQ] := gp[t][[2]];
```

This is utilising `Plot` to generate the curve and look for zero crossings, which we then pass as starting points to `FindRoot`

```
 loc = Flatten[
     t /. # & /@ 
        FindRoot[gpy[t] , Evaluate[ {t, Sequence @@ #[[;; , 1]]}]] & /@ 
          Select[ Partition[ 
           Cases[Plot[ gpy[t], {t, 0, 1}], Line[pts_] :> List[pts], 
               Infinity][[1, 1]] , 2, 1] , #[[1, 2]] #[[2, 2]] <= 0 & ] ]
 Show[{ ParametricPlot[ g[t], {t, 0, 1}], 
      Graphics@{PointSize[.02], Point[g[#] & /@ loc]}} ]
```

[image]

now distinguish min/max by looking at the second derivative:

```
 gpp = g'';
 min = Select[ loc, gpp[#][[2]] > 0 &]
 max = Select[ loc, gpp[#][[2]] < 0 &]
 Show[{ ParametricPlot[ g[t], {t, 0, 1}], 
     Graphics@{Red, PointSize[.02], Point[g[#] & /@ min], Blue, 
     PointSize[.02], Point[g[#] & /@ max]}} ]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd never have hit on that. The problem is solved, thank you. 
But it's a quiet unusual way to solve such problems, isn't it? Doesn't Mathematica offer a simpler solutions?

Comment: I agree its odd there isn't a built in way to do this.  For this case  by the way you could as well do `Table[gpy[t], {t, 0, 1,.01}]` in place of the `Cases[Plot..][[1,1]]` because the function is nice enough we dont really need the adaptive sampling that comes from using `Plot`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
 g = BSplineFunction[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, -1}, {4, 2}}];
 gN[t_?NumericQ] := g[t][[2]]
```

So that  `gN[0.1]` returns a number.

Then

```
 NMinimize[{gN[t], t > 0, t < 1}, t] 
 NMaximize[{gN[t], t > 0, t < 1}, t]
```

(* {1.01494,{t->0.75726}}   {2.48728,{t->0.176073}} *)

works.

Comment: Your method finds the point with the smallest gradient, but i need to find lokal extrema like in
`NMinimize[{Abs@dgN[t], t > 0, t < 1}, t]`
but there exist two of them. And thats my problem. Minimize stops at the first finding

Comment: Just using `g` instead of `g'` should do what you want (at least in this case with only one local min and max )

Comment: the example has two, the first at t~0.17 and the second at t~0.75.
I need this bspline method to evaluate some data, therefore it's important for me to know every extrema.