# Finding the point of minimum distance between two parametric functions

Tags: graphics, mathematical-optimization

I have two functions `re` and `rm`, for which I computed the minimum distance between them.

Now I would like to add a point at the minimum of my distance plot. I tried using `Graphics[Point...]` but somehow couldn't combine the plot and the point into one single graph using `Show[...]`.

Here is my code without the `Point`:

```
re[t_] = {Sin[2 π (t)], (t)^3, (Cos[2 π (t)])^2};
rm[t_] = {1.2*Sin[2 π (t)] + 0.3, (t)^4, 1.1*(Cos[2 π*(t + 0.2)])^2};
Distance[t_] = √((rm[t] - re[t]).(rm[t] - re[t]))
Plot[Distance[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Distance between re and rm", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time t", "Distance"}]
FindMinimum[Distance[t], {t, 2, 3}]
```

If anyone knows how to make this work I would be very thankful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone asked, but: Are you looking for the min distance where `t` is the same? (That is, same time, so to speak.) Or just the min distance between the two parametrized curves. If the latter, then different parameters should be used in the optimization phase. From the `PlotLabel` wording I'm guessing it is the former, which is what responses show how to do. Seemed like something to check all the same, given the wording of the subject.

Answer (score 6):

To see all local minima

```
Plot[Distance[t], {t, 0, 2},
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshFunctions ->
  {ConditionalExpression[Distance'[#], Distance''[#] > 0 && Distance[#] > 0] &},
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Just for fun

```
tab = Table[Sqrt[(rm[t] - re[t]).(rm[t] - re[t])], {t, 0, 1.5, 0.01}];

Block[{p = -Infinity, q = Infinity},
  max = MovingMap[(p = Max[p, Max[#]]) &, tab, 1];
  min = MovingMap[(q = Min[q, Min[#]]) &, tab, 1]];

ListLinePlot[{min, tab, max},
 DataRange -> {0, 1.5},
 GridLinesStyle -> Black,
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 ImageSize -> 600,
 PlotMarkers -> None,
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
```

[image]

```
re[t_] := {Sin[2 Pi t], t^3, (Cos[2 Pi t])^2};
rm[t_] := {1.2 Sin[2 Pi t] + 0.3, t^4, 1.1 (Cos[2 Pi (t + 0.2)])^2};
f[t_] := Sqrt@((rm[t] - re[t]).(rm[t] - re[t]));

d = f'[t] // Simplify;

p1 = Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 2},
   Filling -> Axis,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   PlotRangePadding -> {0, 0.15},
   PlotStyle -> Black,
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed"];

p2 = NumberLinePlot[{d > 0, d < 0, d == 0}, {t, 0, 2},
   PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], Darker@Green},
     {Thickness[0.01], Red}, {PointSize[0.02], Black}},
   ImageSize -> 400,
   Spacings -> 0,
   PlotLegends -> {"Increase", "Decrease", "Minimax"}];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for introducing me to `MovingMap` +1 :)

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun,

```
min = {t /. #2, #1} & @@ NMinimize[Norm[re[t] - rm[t]], {t, 2, 3}];
Manipulate[
 Column[{Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[{re[s], rm[s]}, {s, 0, 2}, 
     BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}], 
    Graphics3D[{{Red, Thick, Line[{re[p], rm[p]}]}, {Purple, Thick, 
       Line[{re[min[[1]]], rm[min[[1]]]}]}}], ImageSize -> 300], 
   Plot[Norm[re[t] - rm[t]], {t, 0, 2}, 
    Epilog -> {{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
       Point[{p, Norm@{re[p] - rm[p]}}], {Purple, PointSize[0.02], 
        Point[min]}}}, ImageSize -> 300]}], {p, 0, 2, 0.05}]
```

Converting `Manipulate` to `Table` and exporting as gif.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use NMinimize instead of FindiMinimum:

> **NMinimize** always attempts to find a global minimum of f subject to the constraints given.
>   .
>
> Except when f and cons are both linear, the results found by **FindMinimum** may correspond only to local, but not global, minima.

```
re[t_] := {Sin[2 Pi t ], t^3, (Cos[2 Pi t])^2};
rm[t_] := {1.2 Sin[2 Pi t] + 0.3, t^4, 1.1 (Cos[2 Pi (t + 0.2)])^2};
Distance[t_] := Sqrt @((rm[t] - re[t]).(rm[t] - re[t]))
fm = NMinimize[Distance[t], {t, 2, 3}]
fm1 = FindMinimum[Distance[t], {t, 2, 3}];
mark[t_] := Reverse /@ Point[t /. # & @@@ #] &;

Plot[Distance[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Distance between re and rm", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time t", "Distance"}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], mark[t]@fm, Red, mark[t]@fm1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note that your distance is equivalent to `Norm[re[t] - rm[t]]` or  `EuclideanDistance[re[t], rm[t]]`

Comment: Ok that worked for this function, but when I try to use the same concept for an other function it doesnt plot the point any more:

re[t_] := {Sin[2 Pi t], t^3, (Cos[2 Pi t])^2};
rm2[t_] = {Sin[2 \[Pi] (t)] + 
    0.4, (t)^4, (Cos[2 \[Pi]*(t + 0.2)])^2};
Distance2[t_] := Sqrt@((rm2[t] - re[t]).(rm2[t] - re[t]))
fm2 = NMinimize[Distance2[t], {t, 2, 3}]

Plot[Distance2[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Distance between re and rm2", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time t", "Distance"}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{t /. fm2[[2]], fm2[[1]]}]}]

Comment: @GregoireDuPasquier `re[t_] := {Sin[2 Pi t], t^3, Cos[2 Pi t]^2}; 
rm2[t_] := {Sin[2 Pi t] + 0.4, t^4, Cos[2 Pi*(t + 0.2)]^2}; 
Distance2[t_] := Norm@(rm2[t] - re[t]);
fm2 = NMinimize[{Distance2[t], 0 <= t}, {t}] ; Plot[
 Distance2[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{t /. fm2[[2]], fm2[[1]]}]}]`

Comment: I don't see what is different, but thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @GregoireDuPasquier In your code `NMinimize[]` is finding a minimum at a negative `t`

Answer (score 5):

Using `NMinimize` to find the global minimum as suggested by belisarius, you can also use  `Mesh` as an alternative to `Epilog` to mark the global minimum:

```
re[t_] := {Sin[2 Pi t], t^3, (Cos[2 Pi t])^2};
rm[t_] := {1.2 Sin[2 Pi t] + 0.3, t^4, 1.1 (Cos[2 Pi (t + 0.2)])^2};
Distance[t_] := Sqrt@((rm[t] - re[t]).(rm[t] - re[t]))
fm = NMinimize[Distance[t], {t, 2, 3}];

mesh = fm[[2, 1, -1]];
Plot[Distance[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
PlotLabel -> "Distance between re and rm", AxesLabel -> {"Time t", "Distance"},
Mesh -> {{mesh}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

Update: An alternative approach is to find the local minima and post-process the graphics output to mark the minimum of the local minima. Using a combination of `MeshFunctions` and `ConditionalExpression` as in @eldo's answer and in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58186/125) in [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58137/125)

```
f = Distance; 
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Distance between re and rm", AxesLabel -> {"Time t", "Distance"},
     Mesh -> {{0}},  MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Red},
     MeshFunctions -> {ConditionalExpression[f'[#], f''[#] > 0 && 0 < # <= 2] &}] /. 
 Point[x_] :> {Point[x], Opacity[.7], PointSize[.05], Blue, Point[Min@x]}
```

[image]

To remove the local minima, change the right-hand-side of `RuleDelayed` to `Point[Min@x]`.