# How to get accurate intersection point values?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, intersection

```
pp=ImplicitRegion[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x,y},pt],{pt,CirclePoints[{0,0.75},
{5,0Degree},4]}]==24 &&(-1+0.04 x^2+0.8 y^2)^3==0.00032 x^2 y^3,{x,y}]
Reduce[Element[{x,y},pp],{x,y}]//LogicalExpand
```

I use above method to find the intersection point value,but 2 hours past, there's no any result.
Then I plot:

```
a=ContourPlot[(-1+0.04 x^2+0.8 y^2)^3==0.00032 x^2 y^3,{x,-6,6},{y,-6,6}];
b=ContourPlot[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x,y},pt],{pt,CirclePoints[{0,0.75},
{5,0Degree},4]}]==24,{x,-6,6},{y,-6,6}];
Show[a,b]
```

It's easy to find there are intersection points.
[image: plot]
How to calculate the intersection points value?

Comment: You have two problems here: your use of inexact numbers like `0.04` and `0.8`, and your use of `EuclideanDistance[]`, which introduces an `Abs[]` that gives solvers trouble.

Comment: Also, after looking into it, it seems the solutions involve the root of a degree-30 polynomial with terribly large coefficients. Do you really need an exact solution?

Comment: I really need exact solution! Within 2 hours, system didn't give me any `solvers trouble` notice.

Comment: But it's been running for two hours, as you say. Again, consider that your asking for the exact solution might be unreasonable, when an approximate one is adequate.

Comment: What's your approximate result?I don't understand why this calculation need long time but I am happy to ask a hard question.

Comment: I would say that it's need to solve a degree-30 polynomial with large coefficients contributes to the long evaluation time. Maybe look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRyOL.png).

Comment: You mean my method is correct? Just need more time for CPU calculation?

Comment: My point was more that your desire for an exact solution is impractical. See [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udHrr.png) too, and note the exponent of the polynomial involved.

Comment: Just to make it clear: exact means a closed-form expression. Approximate solution means floats, like `0.123456`. So if you want numerical values, then your problem can be easily solved. But if you actually want something exact, then you need to solve for the roots of a high-degree polynomial which takes a very long time (and might not even be possible).

Comment: @anderstood,`floats` is ok for me,just like `0.3333` is ok even not `1/3`.

Comment: OK so you should probably edit your question (replace _exact_ with _accurate_ for example). There are many answers on this site (see e.g. [42304](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42304/finding-the-intersection-of-a-curve-with-an-interpolation-function)).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a graphic method: plot the intersection points in `ContourPlot`, extract them, then merge close points:

```
f1[x_, y_] = (-1 + 0.04 x^2 + 0.8 y^2)^3 - 0.00032 x^2 y^3;
f2[x_, y_] = 
  Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pt], {pt, 
     CirclePoints[{0, 0.75}, {5, 0 Degree}, 4]}] - 24.;
plot = ContourPlot[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
  Contours -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {f1[#, #2] - f2[#, #2] &}, 
  Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}}}, PlotPoints -> 400]
pts = plot[[1, 1]][[First@
     Cases[plot, Point[data_] :> data, Infinity]]];
Union[pts, SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 0.1 &)]
(* {{-4.78877, 0.46492}, {-4.2477, -0.488119}, {4.24704, -0.488501}, 
{4.78815, 0.463675}} *)
```

[image]

If you want a greater accuracy, use these points are initial conditions for `FindRoot`:

```
Table[FindRoot[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, Transpose[{{x, y}, p}]], {p, pts}]
 (* {{-4.78887, 0.465097}, {-4.24761, -0.488263}, {4.24761, -0.488263}, 
  {4.78887, 0.465097}} *)
```

Comment: IIRC, [Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46532) was the first to employ `MeshFunctions` for stuff like this.

Comment: I usually use one equation for the contour and the other for a mesh function: `ContourPlot[f1[x, y] == 0, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, ContourStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {f2[#, #2] &}, Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}}}]`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work okay with exact coefficients, over the `Reals`:

```
eqns = Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pt], {pt, 
       CirclePoints[{0, 0.75} // Rationalize, {5, 0 Degree}, 4]}] == 
     24 && (-1 + 0.04 x^2 + 0.8 y^2)^3 == 0.00032 x^2 y^3 // 
   Rationalize;
pp = ImplicitRegion[eqns, {x, y}]
(*
ImplicitRegion[
 Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[-(23/4) + y]^2] +
  Sqrt[Abs[-5 + x]^2 + Abs[-(3/4) + y]^2] +
  Sqrt[Abs[5 + x]^2 + Abs[-(3/4) + y]^2] +
  Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[17/4 + y]^2] == 24 &&
   (-1 + x^2/25 + (4 y^2)/5)^3 == (x^2 y^3)/3125, {x, y}]
*)

sols = Solve[Element[{x, y}, pp], {x, y}, Reals]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.03908, Null}  *)
```

An approximation to `sols`:

```
{x, y} /. N@sols
(*{{-4.24761,-0.488263}, {4.24761,-0.488263}, {-4.78887,0.465097}, {4.78887,0.465097}}*)
```

*Alternate exact solution:*

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[Simplify[eqns, {x, y} ∈ Reals] /. Equal -> Subtract, {y, x}];

exact = Table[
   Root[Function /@ (Take[gb, j] /. {x -> #1, y -> #2}), Take[{i, 1}, j]],
   {i, 4}, {j, 2}];
exact // N
(*{{-4.78887,0.465097}, {-4.24761,-0.488263}, {4.24761,-0.488263}, {4.78887,0.465097}}*)
```

Comment: Hah. `GroebnerBasis[]` is exactly how I got the polynomials in the pictures I was trying to show the OP.

Comment: @J.M. Ah, I didn't notice the pictures at first. I figured `Solve[]` must be using `GroebnerBasis[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I read [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/652/54677) ,I don't think I get a general method to find exact intersection.I post the script as below:

```
FindCrossings2D[{f_, g_}, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, 
ymax_}] := {x, 
y} /. (FindRoot[{f[x, y] == 0, 
   g[x, y] == 
    0}, {{x, #[[1]]}, {y, #[[2]]}}] & /@ (ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 
     0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}][[1, 1]]))
f[x_, y_] := (-1 + 0.04 x^2 + 0.8 y^2)^3 - 0.00032 x^2 y^3;
g[x_, y_] := 
Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pt], {pt, 
 CirclePoints[{0, 0.75}, {5, 0 Degree}, 4]}] - 24;
pts = FindCrossings2D[{f, g}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}]

ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point /@ pts}]
```