# Points of Intersection

Tags: equation-solving

How to numerically find points of intersection between pair of curves (Here,a circle and a parabola) ? Finding it a bit messy as, for a point on one curve, slope of the other is involved.

```
ContourPlot[ (x^2 + y^2 - 4) *( y - x^2 + 2 x - 1) == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4} , ContourStyle -> {Thick, Magenta}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Isn't `NSolve[ {(x^2 + y^2 - 4) == 0 , (y - x^2 + 2 x - 1) == 0}, {x,y}, Reals]` enough for you?

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9928/identifying-critical-points-lines-of-2-3d-image-cubes and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function

Comment: @b.gatessucks it seems so… see post below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindInstance` works as well:

```
fi = FindInstance[(x^2 + y^2 - 4) == 0 && (y - x^2 + 2 x - 1) == 
     0, {x, y}, Reals, 2] // N

{*
{x -> -0.399864, y -> 1.95962}, {x -> 1.85894, y -> 0.737785}
*}

ContourPlot[(x^2 + y^2 - 4)*(y - x^2 + 2 x - 1) == 0, {x, -4, 
  4}, {y, -4, 4}, ContourStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{x, y}] /. fi}]
```

[image]

And we can compare the results of `FindInstance` with `NSolve`

```
nsol = NSolve[{(x^2 + y^2 - 4) == 0, (y - x^2 + 2 x - 1) == 0}, {x, 
   y}, Reals]

{*
{x -> -0.399864, y -> 1.95962}, {x -> 1.85894, y -> 0.737785}
*}

fi == nsol
(*
True
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using this [`great post`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function) of J.M. which defines FindAllCrossings2D

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2 - 4)
g[x_, y_] := (y - x^2 + 2 x - 1)

pts = FindAllCrossings2D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 
     21/5}, Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    PlotPoints -> 85, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Chop;

pl=ContourPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}, 
 Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, Point /@ pts}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

we can check it works

```
 NSolve[{(x^2 + y^2 - 4) == 0, (y - x^2 + 2 x - 1) == 0}, {x,y}, Reals]
```

(* {{x->-0.399864,y->1.95962},{x->1.85894,y->0.737785}} *)

```
Show[pl, 
Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[12], Purple, 
Point[{x, y}] /. 
NSolve[{(x^2 + y^2 - 4) == 0, (y - x^2 + 2 x - 1) == 0}, {x, y},  Reals]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

### MeshFunctions

You can also use a combination of the options `MeshFunctions` and  `Mesh`:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2 - 4)
g[x_, y_] := (y - x^2 + 2 x - 1)

ContourPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5},
 Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False, BaseStyle -> Thick,
 MeshFunctions -> {g[#, #2] - f[#, #2] &},
 Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}}}]
```

[image]

**See also:** [Marking points of intersection between two curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10475/125)

### `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections ``

Using the function `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` to find the intersections:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
cp = ContourPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, -7/2, 4}, {y, -9/5, 21/5}, 
  Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> False, BaseStyle -> Thick];

Show[cp, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.03], 
     Point[Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Normal @ cp]]}]
```

[image]