# Something like MinDetect but for saddle points

Tags: image-processing

MinDetect will find all minima in an array of data of any rank. Is there something similar for finding all stationary points? i.e Given an array of data, find all minima, maxima, and saddle points of any index.

Comment: Even if it does not seem necessary adding an example (with sample data) may improve the speed and likelihood of answers.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Identifying critical points/lines of 2/3D image/cubes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9928/484)