# Segmenting cells from a stained image of cells from microscope

Tags: image-processing, image, segmentation

I have an image which has stained cells and I have to segment all the cells.

But the problem is that the cell boundary is not very distinguished where there is staining done because of the stain.

Can someone kindly help me with segmenting the image and getting cell boundary?

please find the image here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1liPzqZz1AWEgdI5PKNguWXyj8Y70XEGa

[image]

I tried various filters like `RidgeFilter`, `DerivativeFilter`, `GaussianFilter` and combination of them.

I am using Mathematica 12.

Comment: Hi Ved, welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code you have tried in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: @rhermans Thank you so much for correcting my question.  Next time onwards, I will be carefull.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20910/1089), there are public codes to do [ridge detection](http://www2.iap.fr/users/sousbie/disperse/web/html/indexd41d.html).
If I apply it to your image, I get this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which seems to do the job.

Comment: Thank you @chris for your answer. But I am sorry this won't help me as `WatershedComponents` does not give accurate segmentation as you can see that there are a lot of small cells which are not there in the original image, especially in the white regions.

Comment: accurate in the sense that there are a lot of extra cells in the colourise image which are actually not there in the original image.

Comment: No. It also gives extra boundaries. I have to perform force inference on that image of cells which is extremely sensitive toward cell boundaries. Hence, I want the boundaries to be precise.

Comment: You can tune the level of persistence to get a good match to what you consider to be the  best match (which is currently unspecified!)