# Is there a faster way to compose a large number of random Gaussians?

Tags: performance-tuning, image, compile

I'm looking for a more efficient way to generate an image with a large number of randomly coloured Gaussians. Here's the code I'm using:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
(* Don't care about underflow of Exp *)
SetSystemOptions["CheckMachineUnderflow" -> False];

(* The minimum allowable determinant of the covariance matrix *)
detminscale = 0.1;

(* Make an association with the gaussian parameters. Reject with a 
   gaussian with alpha value zero if det constraint is violated *)
MakeGaussian[c_, a_, μ_, Σ_] :=
 If[Det[Σ] < detminscale || ! 
    PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[Σ],
  <|"c" -> {0, 0, 0}, "a" -> 0.0, "μ" -> μ,
   "Σi" -> IdentityMatrix[2]|>,
  <|"c" -> Clip[c, {0, 1}], "a" -> Clip[a, {0, 1}], "μ" -> μ,
   "Σi" -> Inverse[Σ]|>
  ]

(* Evaluates the gaussian on the WxH grid, returning a 2D grid of RGBA tuples *) 
cfEvalGaussian = 
  Compile[{{c, _Real, 1}, {a, _Real}, {m, _Real, 1}, {s, _Real, 2}, {w, _Integer}, {h, _Integer}},
   Table[
    Append[c, 
     a*Clip[With[{X = ({i, j} - m)}, Exp[-X.s.X]], {0, 1}]], {i, 1, h}, {j, 1, w}
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

(* Evaluates the gaussian and converts to an RGBA image *)
EvalGaussian[g_, w_, h_] :=
 Image[cfEvalGaussian[g["c"], g["a"], g["μ"], 
   g["Σi"], w, h], ColorSpace -> "RGB"]

(* We evaluate all gaussians in parallel, the quiet is to silence underflow warnings.
   TODO: other kernels don't respect the CheckMachineUnderflow !? *)
EvaluateAllGaussians[gs_, w_, h_] :=
 ParallelTable[Quiet@EvalGaussian[g, w, h], {g, gs}]

ComposeRGBA[i1_, i2_] := ImageCompose[Image[i1], Image[i2]]

(* Starting from black, compose all the gaussian images over each other *)
ComposeGaussians[gres_, w_, h_] :=
 Fold[ComposeRGBA, ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0, 1}, {w, h}], gres]
```

[image: random 2D gaussians]

And this is how I'm testing it:

```
(* Generates a random positive semi-definite matrix, rejects bad det scales *)
randomGOMtx[scaler_] := Module[{M},
  Until[detminscale < Det[M],
   M = RandomVariate[
     GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[RandomReal[scaler], 2]]
   ];
  Return[M]
  ]

(* Test 500 random colour gaussians at 1024x1024 resolution *)
With[{dmax = 1024, n = 500},
 colours = RandomReal[1, {n, 3}];
 alphas = RandomReal[{0.2, 1}, n];
 means = RandomReal[{1, dmax}, {n, 2}];
 matrices = Table[randomGOMtx[dmax*1.0], n];
 gaussians = 
  MapThread[MakeGaussian, {colours, alphas, means, matrices}];
 evals = EvaluateAllGaussians[gaussians, dmax, dmax];
 ComposeGaussians[evals, dmax, dmax]
 ]
```

I am also looking to try out the 3D case too (with Image3D), but the 2D case takes 2 minutes to produce an image, and 3d is likely to be much slower.

---

Update: This is the 3D case and it's painfully slow.
I've also improved the matrix generation by using rotation matrices.

```
MakeGaussian[c_, a_, μ_, Σi_] :=
 <|"c" -> Clip[c, {0, 1}], "a" -> Clip[a, {0, 1}], "μ" -> μ,
  "Σi" -> Σi|>

cfEvalGaussian = 
  Compile[{{c, _Real, 1}, {a, _Real}, {m, _Real, 1}, {s, _Real, 
     2}, {w, _Integer}, {h, _Integer}, {d, _Integer}},
   Table[
    Append[c, 
     a*Clip[With[{X = ({i, j, k} - m)}, Exp[-X . s . X]], {0, 
        1}]], {i, 1, h}, {j, 1, w}, {k, 1, d}
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

EvalGaussian[g_, w_, h_, d_] :=
 cfEvalGaussian[g["c"], g["a"], g["μ"], g["Σi"], w, 
  h, d]

EvaluateAllGaussians[gs_, w_, h_, d_] :=
 ParallelTable[Quiet@EvalGaussian[g, w, h, d], {g, gs}]

cfComposeRGBA = Compile[{{i1, _Real, 4}, {i2, _Real, 4}},
   With[{w = Length[i1], h = Length[i1[[1]]], 
     d = Length[i1[[1, 1]]]},
    Table[
     With[{c1 = i1[[i, j, k]], c2 = i2[[i, j, k]], 
       a = i2[[i, j, k, 4]]},
      c2*a + c1*(1 - a)
      ], {i, w}, {j, h}, {k, d}]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

randomGOMtx[scaler_] := 
 With[{P = RotationMatrix[{{1, 0, 0}, RandomPoint[Sphere[]]}]},
  Inverse[P] . DiagonalMatrix[1/RandomReal[{.1, scaler}, 3]] . P]

With[{dmax = 256, n = 50},
 colours = RandomReal[1, {n, 3}];
 alphas = RandomReal[{0.2, 1}, n];
 means = RandomReal[{1, dmax}, {n, 3}];
 matrices = Table[randomGOMtx[dmax*2], n];
 gaussians = 
  MapThread[MakeGaussian, {colours, alphas, means, matrices}];
 evals = EvaluateAllGaussians[gaussians, dmax, dmax, dmax];
 Image3D[ComposeGaussians[evals, dmax, dmax, dmax], 
  ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
 ]
```

[image: 3d gaussian cloud]

Comment: I don't find two minutes a long time. How much time does it take for 3D?

Comment: @user64494 haven't finished that yet, but in C++ this takes seconds.

Comment: Me neither. That's why erased the comment ^^

Comment: @flinty: This forum is on Mathematica.

Comment: @user64494 Yes ... I know (?). My question is about improving the Mathematica code which seems unreasonably slow, to get it closer to C++ / native performance. I'm also looking at calling OpenCL from Mathematica as a last resort.

Comment: @flinty: Using a known C++ code in Mathematica is a reasonable solution.

Comment: @flinty A bit on and off topic - during the ongoing WTC I heard some neat GLSL trick is coming, which can be used as some kinds of "universal" render pass for 2D and 3D graphics.

Comment: @flinty If you have a _C++_ implementation already, I can help you with the _LibraryLink_ code (which is really mostly boilerplate). And I also have a bit of experience with _Metal_ (Apple's follow-up for OpenCL). I cannot do OpenCL because my machine does not want to run it anymore.

Comment: Got a trick to [make it under 2 sec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCJNM.png). Will post as answer after a sleep!

Comment: Because it appears you are not making statistical inferences but rather producing a figure, why not just generate a single random sample from a bivariate (or trivariate) normal?  Then you can transform those data points for any mean and covariance matrix you want.

Comment: @JimB Exactly what I did! :D

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher _I cannot do OpenCL because my machine does not want to run it anymore._ I'm getting the same problem in 13.3.1.0 - ```Needs["OpenCLLink`"]``` then run `OpenCLQ[]` and it crashes the kernel - doesn't even reply False. I've filed a bug report.

Comment: Do you run this on a _Mac_? _Apple_ has discontinued _OpenCL_ in favor of _Metal_.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher No, Windows 10. CUDALink works which is even more weird. But I dislike posting CUDA here because OpenCL works on AMD and nvidia cards, and it's more helpful to others who don't have expensive nvidia hardware. I even updated the driver and it still doesn't work. I have a lot of Mathematica+OpenCL code I've built up over the years and now it sadly doesn't work!

Comment: How, yeah. _Then_ you should definitely contact Wolfram Support. (Btw., I also hate being locked-in into CUDA.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I discovered `OpenCLQ[]` crashes the kernel because I had both the _Intel oneAPI DPC C++_ compiler installed and _Visual Studio 2022_. When I uninstalled the Intel one, `OpenCLQ[]` works and returns True! I informed Wolfram.

Answer (score 7):

You use `MapThread` with a `CompiledFunction`. But `CompiledFunction`s have their own threading mechanism, that may also exploit parallel threads. Here is my proposition for you:

```
cfEvalGaussianThread = 
  Compile[{{c, _Real, 1}, {a, _Real}, {m, _Real, 1}, {s, _Real, 2}, {w, _Real}, {h, _Real}},
   Block[{cnew, s11, s12, s22, r2, val},
    s11 = Compile`GetElement[s, 1, 1];
    s12 = Compile`GetElement[s, 1, 2];
    s22 = Compile`GetElement[s, 2, 2];
    Table[
     r2 = -(x s11 x + 2. x s12 y + y s22 y);
     val = Max[0., Min[a, a Exp[r2]]];
     {Compile`GetElement[c, 1], Compile`GetElement[c, 2], Compile`GetElement[c, 3], val}
     , {x, 1. - m[[1]], h - m[[1]], 1.}, {y, 1. - m[[2]], w - m[[2]], 1.}
     ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

On my machine

```
dataThread = cfEvalGaussianThread[
   gaussians[[All, "c"]],
   gaussians[[All, "a"]],
   gaussians[[All, "\[Mu]"]],
   gaussians[[All, "\[CapitalSigma]i"]],
   w, h
   ];
```

is 10 faster than

```
data = ParallelTable[ cfEvalGaussian[g["c"], g["a"], g["\[Mu]"], g["\[CapitalSigma]i"], w, h], {g, gaussians}];
```

It does not convert to `Image`, though. And that is the new bottleneck.

The parallelization in `Compile` is suboptimal, and single precision would suffice for you purpose. So a *C++* implementation might be a good any idear. It is quite easy to create a function callable from *Mathematica* by using *LibraryLink*.

Answer (score 7):

Basically the idea is to draw in vector form, then exploit FrontEnd's ability to `Rasterize` the result.

First we make the base primitive corresponding to a "standard Gaussian" shape.

**Note 1**: To reduce visual artifect, the mesh needs to be based on concentric circles.

**Note 2**: For as many as 500 Gaussian primitives, we probably don't need such a fine detailed mesh, so if we reduce the number of `r` here, we should see an extra performance boost at the final rasterization step.

```
basePts = Module[{r = N@Subdivide[5], Δr, Δl, n, θ0, θmin = 20 °}
            , Δr = Differences@r
            ; Δl = 2 Δr Tan[θmin]
            ; n = Ceiling[(2 π Rest[r])/Δl]
            ; θ0 = π/Most[n] // Prepend[0] // N // Accumulate
            ; MapThread[CirclePoints[{#1, #2}, #3] &, {Rest[r], θ0, n}] // Prepend[{{0., 0.}}]
            ];
baseMesh = Join @@ basePts // DelaunayMesh
```

[image: base mesh]

Then we give each vertices correct intensity, which will later be used to color them:

```
baseVtx = MeshCoordinates[baseMesh];
basePoly = Polygon[MeshCells[baseMesh, 2][[;; , 1]]];
baseIntense = basePts[[;; , 1]]^2 . {1, 1} // 
     Thread[Rule[#, Rescale[Exp[-5 #]]]] & //
    Nearest[#, baseVtx^2 . {1, 1}][[;; , 1]] & // 
   Developer`ToPackedArray;
```

Now we have the primitive, which can be shown like this:

```
GraphicsComplex[baseVtx, basePoly, 
      VertexColors -> Map[GrayLevel[1, #] &, baseIntense]
      ] //
     Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 40, Background -> Black] &
```

[image: standard Gaussian]

The rest work is just to geometrically transform and colorize it. For that we define two helper functions:

```
ClearAll[genTF, genCF]

genTF[regionsize_, scale_] := RightComposition[
        ScalingTransform@RandomPoint@Cuboid[{.1, .1}, scale {1, 1}]
        , RotationTransform@RandomReal[2 π]
        , TranslationTransform@RandomPoint@Cuboid[regionsize {-1, -1}, regionsize {1, 1}]
        ]

genCF[] :=RandomColor[RGBColor[_,_,_]] // Inactive[Function][
                    Append[#, RandomReal[{.1^(1/2), 1}]^2 Inactive[Slot][1]]
                    ] & // Activate
```

Do the plot, 50 Gaussian primitives take a bit more than 1 second:

```
Graphics[{
     Function[{cf, tf}
       , GraphicsComplex[tf@baseVtx, {EdgeForm[], basePoly}, VertexColors -> Map[cf, baseIntense]]
       ] // MapThread[#
        , Table[{genCF[](*GrayLevel[1,#]&*), genTF[5, 4]}, 50]//Transpose
        , 1] &
     }, Background -> Black] //
   Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> 300, Background -> Black] & // 
   AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: 50 Gaussian]

The result should look better (and probably more correct) if we consider gamma correction (for example, consider the `sRGBGamma` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86962/17)):

[image: 50 Gaussian with gamma correction]

---

And generating 500 Gaussian on 1024 size canvas takes only 8 seconds:

[image: 500 Gaussian]

Comment: How would you propose extending this to the 3D case?
I can see how the transformation of a sphere might work, but we don't have the VertexColor blending for tetrahedra.

Comment: @flinty Unfortunately I don't think my approach here can be extended to 3D case. But it's possible an approximate solution can be done through tricks similar to that in [my other post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271827/17).

Comment: @flinty On the second thought, maybe I misunderstood when you meant by "3D case"? Did you mean rasterized but in 3D -- a 3-dimensional array like `Image3D`?

Comment: yes Image3D or something I scan scroll around like in the other post you linked, but also doesn't need to use the Image3D interface, could just generate an image from a projection I suppose.

Comment: @flinty Then I think it should do the job if you `Inset` planar `Image`s in a `Graphics3D` like my other post.

Answer (score 5):

The 3D Case takes just a few seconds using OpenCL. It was a real pain getting *OpenCLLink* to work. I also improved the alpha blending.

[image: 3d gaussians]

```
Remove["Global`*"]
Needs["OpenCLLink`"];
Assert[OpenCLQ[]];
SetSystemOptions["CheckMachineUnderflow" -> False];

kernelGaussian3D = "__kernel void gaussian3D(
__global float4 * out,
__constant float4 * colour,
__constant float4 * mu,
__constant float4 * mtx,
int dim)
{
int index = get_global_id(0);
{
    int z = index % dim;
    int y = ((index - z)/dim)%dim;
    int x = (index - z - dim*y)/(dim*dim);
    float3 p = (float3)(x,y,z) - mu[0].xyz; 

    float3 r;
    r.x = dot(mtx[0].xyz, p);
    r.y = dot(mtx[1].xyz, p);
    r.z = dot(mtx[2].xyz, p);

    float a = colour[0].w * exp(-dot(p, r));
    
    float3 c1 = out[index].xyz;
    float3 c0 = colour[0].xyz;
    float a1 = out[index].w;
    float a0 = a * colour[0].w;

    float aM = (1.f - a0)*a1+a0 + 0.00000001f;
    float4 result;
    result.xyz = ((1.f-a0)*a1*c1+a0*c0)/aM;
    result.w = aM;
    out[index] = result;
}
}";

clGaussian3D = 
  OpenCLFunctionLoad[kernelGaussian3D, 
   "gaussian3D", {{"Float[4]", 1, "InputOutput"}, {"Float[4]", 1, 
     "Input"}, {"Float[4]", 1, "Input"}, {"Float[4]", 1, "Input"}, 
    "Integer32"},
   {8, 8}];

randomGOMtx[scaler_] := 
 With[{P = RotationMatrix[{{1, 0, 0}, RandomPoint[Sphere[]]}]}, 
  Inverse[P] . DiagonalMatrix[1/RandomReal[{.1, scaler}, 3]] . P]

MakeGaussian[c_, μ_, Σi_] := <|"c" -> c, "μ" -> μ, "Σi" -> Σi|>
With[{dmax = 128, n = 50},
 colours = 
  RandomVariate[
   UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0.5, 1}}], n];
 means = RandomReal[{1., dmax}, {n, 3}];
 matrices = Table[randomGOMtx[dmax*1], n];
 gaussians = MapThread[MakeGaussian, {colours, means, matrices}];
 mem = OpenCLMemoryLoad[
   Flatten@ConstantArray[{1., 1., 1., 0.}, dmax^3], "Float"];
 Do[
  clGaussian3D[mem,
    g["c"],
    Append[g["μ"], 0],
    Flatten[Append[#, 0] & /@ g["Σi"]],
    dmax, {dmax^3}];
  , {g, gaussians}];
 im3d = Image3D[
   ArrayReshape[
    OpenCLMemoryGet[mem]
    , {dmax, dmax, dmax, 4}], "Float", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
   Axes -> True];
 OpenCLMemoryUnload[mem];
 im3d
 ]
```

The 2D case is below. Virtually instantaneous!

```
kernelGaussian2D = "__kernel void gaussian2D(
__global float4 * out,
__constant float4 * colour,
__constant float2 * mu,
__constant float2 * mtx,
int dim)
{
int index = get_global_id(0);
{
    int x = index % dim;
    int y = ((index - x)/dim);
    float2 p = (float2)(x,y) - mu[0].xy;    

    float2 r;
    r.x = dot(mtx[0].xy, p);
    r.y = dot(mtx[1].xy, p);

    float a = colour[0].w * exp(-dot(p, r));

    
    float3 c1 = out[index].xyz;
    float3 c0 = colour[0].xyz;
    float a1 = out[index].w;
    float a0 = a * colour[0].w;

    float aM = (1.f - a0)*a1+a0 + 0.00000001f;
    float4 result;
    result.xyz = ((1.f-a0)*a1*c1+a0*c0)/aM;
    result.w = aM;
    out[index] = result;
}
}";
clGaussian2D = 
  OpenCLFunctionLoad[kernelGaussian2D, 
   "gaussian2D", {{"Float[4]", 1, "InputOutput"}, {"Float[4]", 1, 
     "Input"}, {"Float[2]", 1, "Input"}, {"Float[2]", 1, "Input"}, 
    "Integer32"},
   {8, 8}];
MakeGaussian[c_, μ_, Σi_] :=
 <|"c" -> Clip[c, {0, 1}], "μ" -> μ, 
  "Σi" -> Σi|>

randomGOMtx[scaler_] := 
 With[{P = RotationMatrix[{{1, 0}, RandomPoint[Circle[]]}]},
  Inverse[P] . DiagonalMatrix[1/RandomReal[{.1, scaler}, 2]] . P]

With[{dmax = 512, n = 100},
 colours = 
  RandomVariate[
   UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0.5, 1}}], n];
 means = RandomReal[{1., dmax}, {n, 2}];
 matrices = Table[randomGOMtx[dmax*1], n];
 gaussians = MapThread[MakeGaussian, {colours, means, matrices}];
 mem = OpenCLMemoryLoad[
   Flatten@ConstantArray[{1., 1., 1., 0.}, dmax^2], "Float"];
 Do[
  clGaussian2D[mem,
    g["c"],
    g["μ"],
    Flatten@g["Σi"],
    dmax, {dmax^2}];
  , {g, gaussians}];
 im = Image[
   ArrayReshape[
    OpenCLMemoryGet[mem]
    , {dmax, dmax, 4}], "Float", ColorSpace -> "RGB"];
 OpenCLMemoryUnload[mem];
 im
 ]
```

[image: 2d gaussians]

Comment: I think that the following might save you some flops:
`float3 p = (float3)(x,y,z) - mu[0].xyz;
        float3 r = {
            dot(mtx[0].xyz, p),
            dot(mtx[1].xyz, p),
            dot(mtx[2].xyz, p)
        };
        float a = colour[0].w * exp(-dot(p, r));` (It computes the difference `p - mu[0].xyz` just once.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher thanks, added.