# adding noise (or perturbing) to a surface

Tags: graphics

Perhaps a stupid question but I am used to that.

This is a perfect smooth surface with circle contour. How can I add some small noise to it to have an actual moutain look with not so smooth contours

```
fa = E^-(x^2 + y^2)^.5;

min = 0;
max = 1;

f1 = Plot3D[fa, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {min, max}, 
   ClippingStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 15, 
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
   MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.3], 
      RGBColor[0.54938, 0.773313, 0.848103]}, {Opacity[.8], 
      RGBColor[0.9, 0.9, 0.9]}}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 100];
slice = SliceContourPlot3D[fa, 
   z == min - 3, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, min - 3, min + 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {min, max}, Contours -> 20, Axes -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ColorFunction -> "LightTerrain"];
Show[f1, slice, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.5}, 
 FaceGrids -> {Back, Left}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 Ticks -> None, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the *minimum* code necessary for the problem.  Do we really need to know all your RGBColor schemes?  Or FaceGrids?  Or AxesLabels?  Or BoxRatios?  Of label Font choices?  Or ColorFunction?  Or...?????

Comment: Wouldn't `Plot3D[E^-(x^2 + y^2)^.5, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]` include everything you need for your question?

Comment: If you are just interested in adding some random noise you could try something along the lines of `Plot3D[E^-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] RandomReal[{.75, 1.25}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3,
   3}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Not sure what you want to have? 
You want the conturs (=boundaries) to be NOT smooth?
How about a Bessel Function?

Plot3D[BesselJ[0, 3*Sqrt[(x^2 + 2*y^2)]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]

Comment: The proposed solution of Marchi and Paul Saturday fails to generate mountain like contours

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mandelbrot suggested that the fractal surfaces arising from fractional Brownian motion can be used to model rough surfaces in nature, such as mountains. Luckily, Roman Maeder's *The Mathematica Programmer II* (1996) has a chapter on fractional Brownian motion which we can use. I wrote new code for this answer, but the idea in the code is the same as in the code Maeder wrote over twenty years ago.

The algorithm is the following:

1. Generate a grid of values in some manner with $n$ sample points in each direction.
2. Interpolate the grid linearly and refine the grid by sampling it with $n/r$ points in each direction.
3. Add a Gaussian random number to each grid point. If a finer grid is desired, go back to (2).

There are two parameters used in this algorithm. The first one is $r$, which is called the *lacunarity*. For example, if $r = 0.5$ then the number of points is increased by two in each direction every iteration. The other parameter is $h$, the Hurst exponent, which is related to the fractal dimension of the limit surface. The fractal dimension is $3 - h$. Generally, a lower Hurst exponent gives a more noisy surface.

```
step[r_, h_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}][{ox_, oy_, interp_}] := 
 Module[{delta, nx, ny, t, T},
  nx = Ceiling[ox/r];
  ny = Ceiling[oy/r];
  t = 1./(Max[{nx, ny}] - 1);
  T = 1./(Max[{ox, oy}] - 1);
  delta = Sqrt[0.5] Sqrt[1 - (t/T)^(2 - 2 h)] t^h;
  {
   nx,
   ny,
   Interpolation[Flatten[Outer[
      {{#, #2}, interp[#, #2] + delta RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]} &,
      Subdivide[xmin, xmax, nx],
      Subdivide[ymin, ymax, ny]
      ], 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1]
   }
  ]
```

Here we create an initial grid with values from the given function and visualize the linear interpolation. There are ten grid points in each direction:

```
init = Flatten[Outer[
    {{#, #2}, E^-(#^2 + #2^2)^.5} &,
    Subdivide[-3, 3, 10],
    Subdivide[-3, 3, 10]
    ], 1];
interp = Interpolation[init, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Plot3D[
 interp[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotRange -> Full,
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["GreenBrownTerrain"],
 Mesh -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we refine the grid four times with $r = 0.5$, i.e. we double the number of grid points in each direction four times. The Hurst exponent is 0.75.

```
{nx, ny, f} = Nest[step[0.5, 0.75, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}], {10, 10, interp}, 4];
Plot3D[
 f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotRange -> Full,
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["GreenBrownTerrain"],
 Mesh -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As we can see, new rough detail has appeared on the surface. Setting `fa = f[x,y]` we can see how this looks with the visualization technique in the OP:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Other parameter values will result in different looking surfaces, depending on what one wants it might be worth it to try a few different ones.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a 2D Gaussian random field taking code from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/efficiently-generating-n-d-gaussian-random-fields/4933#4933). Here I've used the `fields` function from my own answer but any of them would work.

For this approach you're plotting a dataset instead of a function so use `ListPlot3D`.

```
n = 300;    
smooth = Table[E^-(x^2 + y^2)^.5, {x, -3, 3, 6/(n - 1)}, {y, -3, 3, 6/(n - 1)}];
rand = -0.5 + Rescale@First@fields[n, -3.5];

m = smooth + 2 smooth rand;

ListPlot3D[m, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"SandyTerrain", "Reverse"}], 
 PlotRange -> {0.05, Max[m]}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
 ClippingStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0.4, 0.6], BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.2}]
```

[image]