# How to pad periodically a cube to be compatible with ListInterpolation?

Tags: list-manipulation, algebra, periodic-function

### Context

I would like to define a periodic interpolation function on a cube.
It seems mathematica's `ListInterpolation` and the option 
`PeriodicInterpolation -> True` cannot cope with a cube 
which is not explicitly periodic. So I need to pad periodically this cube
so as to interpolate it.

### Question

> How to pad a given cube so that `ListInterpolation` over this padded cube accounts for periodicity?

### Attempt

Let me start with a trivial  cube

```
dat = Range[2^3] // Partition[#, {2}] & // Partition[#, {2}] &
```

Following [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6197271/1353714) MrWizard's nifty command periodically pads the cube

```
 dat = PadRight[dat, Dimensions[dat] + 1];
 a = {0, 1}~Tuples~TensorRank[dat]~SortBy~Tr // Rest;
 MapThread[(dat[[Sequence @@ #]] = dat[[Sequence @@ #2]]) &, {-a, 
    a} /. 0 -> All];
```

Now `dat` has the right structure for ListInterpolation

{{{1, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 3}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{5, 6, 
5}, {7, 8, 7}, {5, 6, 5}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 
3}, {1, 2, 1}}}

And indeed Mathematica's ListInterpolation takes the periodic table

```
f = ListInterpolation[dat,PeriodicInterpolation -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0]

 dat[[2, 1, ;; -2]]
```

{10,11,12}

```
 Table[f[2, 1, x], {x, 1, 3}]
```

{10,11,12}

and the interpolation is indeed periodic

```
Table[f[2, 1, x], {x, 1, 6}]
```

{10,11,12,10,11,12}

But if I apply the same technique to a random table

```
dat =RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3^3]//Partition[#, {3}] & //Partition[#, {3}] &
dat =PadRight[dat, Dimensions[dat] + 1];a ={0, 1}~Tuples~TensorRank[dat]~SortBy~Tr // Rest;
MapThread[(dat[[Sequence @@ #]]=dat[[Sequence @@ #2]]) &,{-a,a}/.0 -> All];
f = ListInterpolation[dat,PeriodicInterpolation -> True,InterpolationOrder-> 0]
```

Even though the cube has been made periodic:

```
dat[[2, 1, ;;]]
```

{0.87581,-0.125233,-0.497163,0.87581}

The interpolation produces nonsense

```
 Table[f[2, 1, x], {x, 1, 3}]
```

{-0.305603,-0.305603,-1.6259}

My guess is that I am missing something obvious, but the answer might be of interest to this community nonetheless? I wish the builtin function would 
deal transparently with this !

### Update

When considering it more globally,the solution does not seem to be fully satisfactory.

If I generate a 16x16 Gaussian random field using [this function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9951/1089).

```
 dat = GaussianRandomField[nn = 16, 2, Function[k,k^(-1.5)]]//Chop//GaussianFilter[#, 4] &;
```

Then

```
dat = PadRight[dat, Dimensions[dat] + 1];a = {0,1}~Tuples~TensorRank[dat]~SortBy~Tr//Rest;
MapThread[(dat[[Sequence @@ #]] = dat[[Sequence @@ #2]]) &, {-a, 
    a} /. 0 -> All]; dat[[;; , ;;]] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then the `ListInterpolation` does not seem to be truly periodic.

```
f = ListInterpolation[dat, PeriodicInterpolation -> True];
Map[ f @@ # &, Outer[List, Range[32], Range[32]], {2}] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the problem seems to arise from the Gaussian Filtering which is not periodic. If periodic Filtering is done in Fourrier Space (via the `Exp[-( k/2)^2]` cutoff), then it seems to work:

```
dat = GaussianRandomField[nn=16,3,Function[k, Exp[-(k/2)^2]k^(-1.5)]] //Chop; 
dat = PadRight[dat, Dimensions[dat] + 1];
a = {0, 1}~Tuples~TensorRank[dat]~SortBy~Tr // Rest;
MapThread[(dat[[Sequence @@ #]] = dat[[Sequence @@ #2]]) &, {-a,a} /. 0 -> All]; 
dat[[;; , ;; , 1]] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then the interpolation seems to work:

```
f = ListInterpolation[dat, PeriodicInterpolation -> True,
   InterpolationOrder -> 3]; Map[ f @@ # &,  
  Outer[List[#1, #2, 1] &, Range[Length[dat]*2], 
   Range[Length[dat]*2]], {2}] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also true when slicing in the other direction:

```
Map[ f @@ # &,  Outer[List[#1, 1, #2] &, Range[Length[dat]*2], 
   Range[Length[dat]*2]], {2}] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It can be encapsulated as follows

```
Clear[ListInterpolationPeriodic]; 
ListInterpolationPeriodic[dat_List, opts___] := Module[{a, dat1},
  dat1 = PadRight[dat, Dimensions[dat] + 1];
  a = {0, 1}~Tuples~TensorRank[dat]~SortBy~Tr//Rest;
  MapThread[(dat1[[Sequence @@ #]]=dat1[[Sequence @@ #2]]) &,{-a,a}/. 0-> All];
  ListInterpolation[dat1, PeriodicInterpolation -> True,opts]]

f = ListInterpolationPeriodic[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

All the credits goes to MrWizard.