# Displacing / warping an image using a pre-existing optical flow image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

[`ImageDisplacements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDisplacements.html) provides a way to calculate the displacements between two images (e.g for optical flow purposes) and return a two channel image containing the dx,dy displacements.

What should I do if I already have a two channel image of displacements and want to warp an existing image? i.e how can I use an image to warp another image?

Suppose I have this warped image `newimg`:

[image: warped]

... which originally came from:

```
testimg = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House2"}], 512];
```

Without knowing the transformation, but given an optical flow image:

```
ImageAdjust@Image[
  First@ImageDisplacements[{testimg, newimg}]
 ]
```

[image: optical flow]

... how can I use this to "*unwarp*" the distorted image efficiently back into something resembling the original?

Comment: Related but in the forward direction [(234688)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234688/how-to-recreate-this-image-warping-effect) , also my intent is to try to apply this to my other question [(253252)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253252/animating-curl-noise-applied-to-an-image)

Comment: I would compute corresponding feature points in the two images then estimate a two-dimensional interpolation function, then apply it to the image you seek to alter.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't have two images to get correspondences from - I only have the warped image, and the displacement image (colourful thing at the end) - the original unwarped image which is the desired result has only been provided for the purposes of calculating the distortion map and measuring the quality.

Comment: Then I would fit the displacement image with a two dimensional function ($\Delta x , \Delta y)$ as a function of position, then use ImageTransformation applied to your given image (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTransformation.html).

Comment: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ImageWarping/